# When does the game end when the last player pushes the first player over the 40-point limit?

Tags: the-agents

In a three-player game, the first player had about 38 points.  It is the last player's turn, and he uses a Free Agent which gives the first player (whose turn will normally be next) 41 points, triggering the game ending condition.  The last player then ends his turn and collects points, which also pushes the last player over 40.  Does the game end immediately, or does it go for one more round?

We played one further round, under the logic that: 1) the first player went over 40 first, off-turn. 2) the rules state that "When a player reaches 40 points at the end of their turn..." and 3) since he was first player, everyone else gets a turn to act so that everyone would get the same number of points.

On the other hand, the argument for the game ending immediately is: the last player went over 40 at the end of his turn (his turn ended on 40 first), and since everyone had played the same number of turns, the game ends.

Which is correct?

Comment: I don't understand the question; you're saying the first *and* last players both have over 40 points. Why would the game go for another round?

Answer (score 1):

**The game ends immediately after someone has 40+ intel points.** You must have a different version of the [rulebook](http://thoughtprocess.me/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/rules_08_PnP1.pdf). The copy on the playtheagents website states twice:

> **The Goal** - Your goal is simple - to be the first player to reach 40 intel points.
>
> **Reminder**: the first person to reach 40 intel points, wins.

There is no mention of ending the game only on a players turn when they have 40+ intel points, nor requiring all players to have the same number of turns.

Comment: Yes, I was looking at the Kickstarter First Edition rulebook. Under "Winning," that book states, "Once a player has collected 40 or more IPs, that player finishes their turn. Play continues until all players have had an equal number of turns. Once all players finish their last turn, the player with the most IPs is the winner."

Comment: @CodexArcanum, you can choose to play it as written, but usually i assume that updates to the rules (later editions) or online rules are the **official** rules.